# How do we process/scale variable size batches in Apache Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am running a spark streaming process where I am getting batch of data after n seconds.  I am using repartition to scale the application.  Since the repartition size is fixed we are getting lots of small files when batch size is very small.  Is there anyway I can change the partitioner logic based on the input batch size in order to avoid lots of small files.